# WebAPI 2 Unit Test Error with method reference Service

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have a project WebAPI2 with controllers that reference a few other services, I know that everything works fine because I already have the webapi published and working but right now I want to make some unit tests. **In my original solution I created a new Test project and I created my test method**:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void GetVerifyLogin_ShouldReturnUser() {
        UserAccountController controller = new UserAccountController();
        var result = controller.GetVerifyLogin("2171251", "2171251");
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

When I ran the test I got the following error:

> Result Message:    Test method
>   StagesApiMsaTest.UserAccountControllerTest.GetVerifyLogin_ShouldReturnUser
>   threw exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find
>   default endpoint element that references contract
>   'RapidFunctionsService.R_Service' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element.

The method that I'm testing has a few lines of code but I will put an extract of the method:

```
 foreach (var siteItem in siteResult.ResultSet)
                    {
                        result.SiteNum = siteItem.SiteNum;
                        result.DevNum = siteItem.DevNum;
                        result.TrasmitterCode = siteItem.TransmitterCode;
                    }

                    RapidFunctionsService.R_ServiceClient service = new RapidFunctionsService.R_ServiceClient();
                    RapidFunctionsService.ZipCodeVerifyDealerResult xipResult = service.ZipCodeVerifyForXmit(result.TrasmitterCode);
                    result.ZipCodeVerify = xipResult.ZipCodeVerifyDealer;
                    result.ZipCode = xipResult.ZipCode;
```

Anyone have any insight why I'm getting this error in the tests?

Comment: The method under test is tightly coupled to implementation concerns that do not appear to function outside of an actual running environment. encapsulate those dependencies so that they can be mocked to allow the code to be unit tested in isolation.

Comment: Also the last few lines of the error message should be investigated. Are you missing configuration information that should be present in the test project.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about if I need any configuration file in the test project, because the test project is under the same solution and referenced the default webapi project

Comment: the test project is executed under its own context and will need its own config file

Comment: Okay, I got you, let me try that, so I need to create like an app.config on my test project and reference my services?

Comment: If you want to hit the actual service, Yes. this however changes the test to an integration test and not a unit test. To truly isolate the method you need to refactor the code to rely on explicit dependencies that can be mocked/stubbed/faked when testing

Comment: Check the answer provided by @SergeyBerezovskiy which shows what I was explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test classes in isolation when you do unit-testing. That is achieved by mocking class dependencies. In order to mock dependencies, you should pass (inject) them to the class, e.g. via constructor injection. Also, your class should depend on abstractions (i.e. interfaces or abstract classes) rather than implementations. That makes your code *testable*:

```
public class UserAccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRServiceClient rServiceClient;

    // class does not have hidden dependencies
    public UserAccountController (IRServiceClient rServiceClient)
    {
        this.rServiceClient = rServiceClient;
    }

    public ActionResult GetVerifyLogin()
    {
        //...

        foreach (var siteItem in siteResult.ResultSet)
        {
             result.SiteNum = siteItem.SiteNum;
             result.DevNum = siteItem.DevNum;
             result.TrasmitterCode = siteItem.TransmitterCode;
        }

        // instead of creating dependency here, you are use injected dependency
        var xipResult = rServiceClient.ZipCodeVerifyForXmit(result.TrasmitterCode);
        result.ZipCodeVerify = xipResult.ZipCodeVerifyDealer;
        result.ZipCode = xipResult.ZipCode;  

        //...          
    }
}
```

Now you can mock service dependency and test your controller in isolation. E.g. with [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) (there are a lot of other mocking frameworks around):

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetVerifyLogin_ShouldReturnUser()
{
    var rServiceClient = Substitute.For<IRServiceClient>();
    rServiceClient.ZipCodeVerifyForXmit("foo").Returns("bar"); // just an example

    var controller = new UserAccountController(rServiceClient);
    var result = controller.GetVerifyLogin("2171251", "2171251");
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

This example shows how to pass fake dependency which is configured to return a predefined result for predefined input. That makes your controller tests *repeatable*.

Further reading: [Unit tests are F.I.R.S.T.](https://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation it is really very helpful for me because I'm new with tests. Thanks

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera :) I strongly recommend you to read linked article - following these guidelines will improve your unit-testing a lot

Comment: Thanks, I will do it for sure.